# Deployment Assembly configuration not working with mvn package

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee, m2eclipse

Below is the maven project structure I have in eclipse:

[image]

And the deployment assembly configuration is as shown below:

[image]

If I package the war with maven command (mvn clean package) and deploy the war on tomcat, the "resource" folder under WEB-INF is not getting created as I mentioned in deployment assembly configuration.
The server side folder structure created after deployment is as in the image below:

[image]

But, if I export the war from eclipse **"Right click on project -> Export -> War file"** and deploy in tomcat, it is creating the "resources" folder.

[image]

Kindly help me with this. 
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation for the maven-war-plugin here:

[maven-war-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html)

You'll see that by default the contents of the "resources" folder gets placed inside the "classes" folder inside the WAR, so for a maven build you should find your resources in there.

Your Eclipse configuration is different, placing the resources in a separate "resources" folder under WEB-INF. Exporting from Eclipse will use this configuration rather than the maven configuration.

I would recommend changing your Eclipse configuration to match the maven one by changing the Deploy Path to "WEB-INF/classes"

Comment: Thank you Nick:) It worked! But there should be some work-around for eclipse configurations to result in maven packaging.